# Named Credentials OAuth Sharepoint Microsoft Access Control Service Cust Auth. Provider

Tags: apex, oauth2, namedcredentials, sharepoint

I have SalesForce and SharePoint connected on OAuth.
I have created Sharepoint app-only, added it to Custom Auth provider and created namedcredentials which is showing as authenticated.
Every blog post is saying that named credentials would take care of Authentication.
But in my case it is giving me null Authorization header in my rest callout.And the REST callout is failing.
Do we need to still pass the access token by receiving the Auth code from the OAuth-Only Initialization URL(from custom auth provider)?

`req.setEndpoint('callout:SPSF/getbytitle(\''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(val)+'\')/items'); 
req.setMethod('GET');
//string token= GetJWT(); If I use this it works fine
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'bearer ' + token);
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json/x-www-form-urlencoded');`

Because for REST callout we get the type auth. code from Oauthorize.aspx page.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your authentication provider is working correctly (and it appears so based on *Authenticated* being the status), it has obtained a valid access token. You can then include the access token in your callout by using a [merge field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_merge_fields.htm)

```java
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer {!$Credential.OAuthToken}');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solved my issue. Don't need to pass the auth access token. Earlier I was checking to see why named creds was not handling the Authorization. It was because I was not passing the correct Headers. I have corrected the header from 
`req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json/x-www-form-urlencoded');` to `req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');`.
Then I changed the Get to POST.